# How to edit data in crud operations in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to make CRUD app in django

I am trying to collect data from form and trying to display the data in form of tables

So the user can read, delete, update or delete the data

I completed other 3 operation but I am not able to find the error in update table operation

I am attaching my code below please help me

thankyou

I am trying to use bootstrap models to edit the data, however on clicking the edit button the popup is not showing, I am expecting to edit the data once is displayed in form of tables

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/assets/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/assets/css/main-style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/assets/css/responsive.css">
</head>

<body>
    {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert " role="alert">
        <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-inner-wrapper">
                <h1>Please List The Task with title,description and Duedate</h1>
                <div class="task-table">
                    <form class="row g-3" action="/" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label><br>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" aria-describedby="title" name="title">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
                            <br>
                            <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" name="description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="Due-Date" class="form-label">Due-Date</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="duedate" class="form-control" id="date" aria-describedby="date">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4 text-center">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>The tasks are listed below</h1>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for task in task_list %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ task.title }}</td>

                        <td>{{ task.description }}</td>

                        <td>{{ task.duedate }}</td>

                        <td>
                            <form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_task' task.id %}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="task_id" value="{{ task.id }}">
                                <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                            </form>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                data-bs-target="#editModal{{ item.id }}">
                                EDIT
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Bootstrap Modal -->
            {% for item in data %}
            <div class="modal fade" id="editModal{{ item.id }}" tabindex="-1"
                aria-labelledby="editModal{{ item.id }}" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="editModal{{ item.id }}">EDIT YOUR TASK</h1>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form method="post" action="{% url 'edit_data' item.id %}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ form.as_p }}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <script src="../static/assets/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.5.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

MODELS.PY

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Tasks(models.Model):  
   title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   description=models.TextField()
   duedate=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.http import HttpResponse
from home.models import Tasks
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import TasksForm
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
         title=request.POST.get('title')
         description=request.POST.get('description')
         duedate=request.POST.get('duedate')
         task=Tasks(title=title,description=description,duedate=duedate)
         task.save()
        #  messages.success(request, "tasks details updated.")
        task_list = Tasks.objects.all()
        return render(request,'index.html',{'task_list': task_list})

def delete_task(request, task_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            task = Tasks.objects.get(pk=task_id)
            task.delete()
        except Task.DoesNotExist:
            pass  # Handle the case where the record does not exist
    return redirect('index')
def edit_data(request, item_id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Tasks, id=item_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TasksForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')  # Redirect to the view displaying the data table
    else:
        form = TasksForm(instance=instance)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
def create_record(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TasksForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('success_page')
    else:
        form = TasksForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('delete_task/<int:task_id>/', views.delete_task, name='delete_task'),
     path('create/', views.create_record, name='create_record'),
    path('edit/<int:item_id>/', views.edit_data, name='edit_data'),
    
]
```

FORMS.PY

```
from django import forms
from .models import Tasks

class TasksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = ['title', 'description','duedate']  # List the fields you want in the form
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your modal that does not show up, in INDEX.HTML, you have 2 "id" attributes with the same value :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal{{ item.id }}"
```

and inside the modal :

```
<h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="editModal{{ item.id }}">
```

"id" attributes must be unique in the page.

Hope it helps